# Date formatting in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a "start_date" column in which data is in following format:

```
2018-03-15T00:01:00.000Z
2017-01-14T00:01:00.000Z
2017-01-14T00:01:00.000Z
2017-01-14T00:01:00.000Z
2017-01-14T00:01:00.000Z
```

I tried converting the above format to "yyyy-mm-dd" using the below code but it returns the results in the previous format (with T00:01:00.000Z):

```
print(pd.to_datetime(row['start_date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore'))
```

Result has to be in the below format:

```
2018-03-15
2017-01-14
2017-01-14
2017-01-14
2017-01-14
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Comment: @wjandrea: It returns the results in the previous format (with T00:01:00.000Z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried converting the above format to "yyyy-mm-dd"

**No**. That's not the purpose of `pd.to_datetime`. `datetime` series are stored internally as integers. Any date-like representation you see of a `datetime` is just that, a *representation*.

The `format` argument refers to the *input* format, not the output. In this case, to convert to `datetime`, you don't need to specify format:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], errors='coerce')

print(df)

                   dt
0 2018-03-15 00:01:00
1 2017-01-14 00:01:00
2 2017-01-14 00:01:00
3 2017-01-14 00:01:00
4 2017-01-14 00:01:00
```

To return the date only would be a subsequent step which involves changing your series to `object` dtype:

```
df['dt'] = df['dt'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)

           dt
0  2018-03-15
1  2017-01-14
2  2017-01-14
3  2017-01-14
4  2017-01-14
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to just get the results in "YYYY-MM-DD" format?